# Ruby time in milli seconds

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby method

```
 def generate_CurrentDateTime()
            puts "Generating current date and time";
            dateTimeObj = Time.now();       
            dateTimeObj.year.to_s + dateTimeObj.month.to_s + dateTimeObj.day.to_s + 
            dateTimeObj.hour.to_s + dateTimeObj.min.to_s + dateTimeObj.sec.to_s;
 end
```

I would like to add milliseconds in this tried millis.to_s and ms.to_s both are incorrect please help

I already fould an alternative solution

```
def generate_CurrentDateTime()
        puts "Generating current date and time";    
        Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L');
end
```

But i wanna know if any direct method is available.

Comment: can you please add your route file endpoint

Comment: DefaultShutdownStrategy will try to allow existing exchanges to run to completion (where practicable), while rejecting new messages. This allows for a reasonably clean shutdown, when a system has some level of load. But the default shutdown will kill routes with active exchanges if those exchanges do not complete in a specific time. When Camel is used as part of some larger system, it usually isn't practicable to leave stalled exchanges to take as long as they like to finish -- if they haven't finished in the default five minutes, they likely never will. Have I understood the question?

Answer (score 0):

The default shutdown strategy is to gracefully complete all in flight tasks, which means for batch consumers (like the file consumer) it will finish processing the subsequent steps in the route until the end, but will not process more items in the batch because that could be forever. Only the in process task message goes to completion.

You can override this behavior if you know it will eventually finish with the ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteAllTasks parameter:

```
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(url).routeId("foo").noAutoStartup()
                // let it complete all tasks during shutdown
                .shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteAllTasks)
                .process(new MyProcessor())
                .to("mock:bar");
        }
```